# CSS Animation that moves continually

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I have a CSS animation which i have created which simulates water travelling down a tunnel. It uses only one image which i also created. The animation works but doesnt move smoothly. I want the animation to continually move from right to left where the animation has a fixed width of say 500/600px.

Heres the code I have so far:

```
@-moz-keyframes waves{
    0%{
        left:0
    }

    100%{
        left:-580px
    }

}



body{
    background:#e6e6e5;
    overflow:hidden
}

.waves{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;   
    width:640px;
    z-index:0;
    opacity:0.75
}

.waves .wave{
    left: 150px;
    position:absolute;
    width:1200px;
    height:100px;
    background-image:url(images/flow.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x
}

.waves .wave.bottom-wave{
    -moz-animation:waves 10s infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation:waves 17s infinite linear;
    animation:waves 10s infinite linear;
    bottom:164px
}

<html>
   <body>
      <div class="waves">           
       <div class="wave bottom-wave"></div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you add your relevant html so we can make a fiddle/pen of this? Or could you make a jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: Hi @JustinBreiland I have added the html and also a link to the animation, it is in the very basic stages but I think it shows what i am trying to achieve.

Comment: I see no animation there in Chrome.

Comment: @isherwood Yeah sorry i was using firefox to develop. Altered the code now so it should be working in chrome.

Comment: @raymar It's been a while, but any chance of updating the image link so we can see the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of moving it 100% to the left, make it at least twice the container's size and after half of that has passed by jump back to the first state. That way you never reach the end.

Because I was too lazy to find out how long one wave period is I just took the image twice and reset after the image's width has passed (708px).

```css
@-moz-keyframes waves {
    0%{
        margin-left: 0;
    }

    100%{
        margin-left: -708px; /* end after exactly one image width */
    }
}

.waves {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 20px;
    width: 800px;
    height: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.waves .wave{
    margin-left: 0;

    width: 1416px; /* twice the image's width */
    height: 80px;
    background-image: url(http://quarter.cs.stir.ac.uk/~rsm/images/flow.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

.waves .wave.bottom-wave{
    -moz-animation:waves 10s infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation:waves 17s infinite linear;
    animation:waves 10s infinite linear;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="waves">           
        <div class="wave bottom-wave"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Note that I cross-site linked your wave image, change that back if you decide to copy and paste this. Also I changed the wave to use relative positioning and `margin-left` because absolute positioning has no advantage and is just harder to maintain (especially with responsive stuff).

Comment: nice solution, way better than the one I was about to post.

Comment: I can only guess what your solution would've been like, but... two waves?

Comment: Yeah, I used :before to create a second wave.